# Screener Like Google finance

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have any idea how to build a histogram like this on-the-fly? It is a pretty cool trick that I would love to know how to do it in jQuery.
http://www.google.com/finance/stockscreener

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try **[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)**

Comment: Any specific techniques that you would recommend to use? like, how to efficiently create this? I can think of there are around 3000 stocks in the universe, if you send out 3000 data points through json wouldn't this be kinda inefficient?